# Date changes while importing excel file in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have multiple excel files (160) where one 'date' column about 100 observations is in not in proper format. While exporting all the files together the date column changes as follows

Date Column in Excel

| Date |
| --- |
| 05-07-2015 |
| 04-07-2015 |
| 03-07-2015 |
| 02-07-2015 |
| ....... |

Date column importing in R

| Date |
| --- |
| 42190 |
| 42189 |
| 42188 |
| 42187 |
| ...... |

How to change "42191" to original date format?

Comment: you may have a problem with cell formatting in excel, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447813/excel-weird-behaviour-with-dates-text) for similar issue

Comment: I was able to get your date by `as.Date(42191, origin = "1901-04-10")`. But why your origin is 1901-04-10.

Comment: Sorry .. type . heres the proper date output and Input

Comment: What package and exact  function are you using to read the file?

Comment: package (readxl )..

read_plus <- function(flnm) {
  read_xlsx(flnm, sheet = "sheet1" ,   range = cell_cols(9:20)) %>% 
    mutate(filename = flnm)
}


Sheet1 <-  
  list.files(pattern="*.xlsx", 
             full.names = F) %>% 
  map_df(~read_plus(.))

Answer (score 1):

Excel may save dates as numeric or maybe they imported in a numeric format. So you can try:

```
# from Windows Excel:
as.Date(42190, origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "2015-07-05"

# from Mac Excel: 
as.Date(42190, origin = "1904-01-01")
```

Interestingly, Excel support [page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487) define the origin date for Windows excel as "1900-01-01", but from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/) and [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/270455.html) you can see that for R, date of "1899-12-30" should use as the origin date.

Answer (score 0):

copy your date column and special paste it as value in other column and use that to import in R

Comment: yes .. But I have multiple sheets and multiple tabs .. 160 excels * 4 tabs .. i am dynamically importing them ... is there any other way in R ?

Comment: unfortunately you can't change it back in R, but u can select columns and paste values, in this case u must repeat it 4 times. please remove your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be quite helpful:

```
library(openxlsx)
dates <- c(42190,42189,42188,42187)

datesConverted <- convertToDate(dates); datesConverted
# "2015-07-05" "2015-07-04" "2015-07-03" "2015-07-02"
```

Gives you exactly what you're looking for.